# Geddy/NodeJS scaffold error

Tags: node.js, geddy

I'm new into node.js and i chose geddy to start one sample app.
I tried to execute this command:

```
geddy scaffold news title:string
```

but when I run the application, i received an error

```
Error: 500 Internal Server Error
TypeError: ejs:11
<%- linkTo(news[i].title, newsPath(news[i].id)); %>

string is not a function
at handleErr (C:\Users\tschl_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\geddy\lib\template\engines\ejs.js:58:15)
at Object.rethrow (C:\Users\tschl_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\geddy\lib\template\engines\ejs.js:90:41)
at eval (eval at (C:\Users\tschl_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\geddy\lib\template\engines\ejs.js:88:10), :2:925)
at C:\Users\tschl_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\geddy\lib\template\engines\ejs.js:101:17
at ejs.render (C:\Users\tschl_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\geddy\lib\template\adapters\ejs.js:28:10)
at Adapter.render (C:\Users\tschl_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\geddy\lib\template\adapters\index.js:122:22)
at Partial.renderSelf (C:\Users\tschl_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\geddy\lib\template\partial.js:128:28)
at handleData (C:\Users\tschl_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\geddy\lib\template\partial.js:101:16)
at C:\Users\tschl_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\geddy\lib\template\partial.js:119:9
at fs.js:266:14
```

i think that this error is happening by the singular/plural problem,
because when i removed the call to "newsPath", this worked.
Anyone know how to make it work?

Comment: Looks like you found a legitimate bug, would you mind reporting it in github issues? https://github.com/mde/geddy/issues

Comment: Done, https://github.com/mde/geddy/issues/388
Thanks, i will wait now ;)